# What is the average life expectancy of heavy duty ratchet straps before they have to be replaced?

Tags: safety

What is the average life expectancy of heavy duty ratchet strps before they have to be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible to answer.  It depends on the quality of the ratchet mechanism, how well the straps grip, how tight you are tightening the straps (stretch straps and wear out locking mechanism), the amount of force on the straps (is the straps holding something down vs. holding something up), and the acceleration force on the straps (example you tie something down in the back end of your truck and slam on the brakes).

Comment: If enough acceleration force is applied to any strap it can break the first time you use it.